# Force Loading of all Related Entities within Entity without knowing Entity Class Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, xml-serialization, type-conversion

I'm trying to serialize an entity and all its related entities for storing as xml before physically deleting the entity (leaving an audit trail).

I'm using a `DataContractSerializer` which seems to be getting around the shallow serialization performed when using an `XmlSerializer`.

The only trouble is that only related entities that have been loaded get serialized.

I've tried to create a helper function that will take any entity and iterate though its properties looking for related entities to load, however its failing on `EntityCollection` properties because I can't cast them to `EntityCollection<EntityObject>`. I was trying to use `EntityObject` as I figured polymorphism would come to my aid, but the property won't cast complaining it's a different type.

Any ideas?

```
/// <summary>
/// Forces loading of all related entities.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="processed">Processed entities, used to prevent infinite looping.</param>
private static void LoadAllRelatedEntities(EntityObject entity, List<EntityKey> processed)
{
    // Check we haven't already processed this entity
    foreach (EntityKey key in processed)
    {
        if (entity.EntityKey == key)
            return; // Exit without doing anything more with this entity
    }

    processed.Add(entity.EntityKey);

    // Pull in all child entities
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.PropertyType == typeof(EntityReference) || p.PropertyType.BaseType == typeof(EntityReference))
        {
            if (p.GetValue(entity, null) != null)
            {
                EntityReference e = (EntityReference)p.GetValue(entity, null);
                if (!e.IsLoaded)
                    e.Load();

                // Load child entities
                IEnumerator eEnum = e.GetEnumerator();
                while (eEnum.MoveNext())
                {
                    LoadAllRelatedEntities((EntityObject)eEnum.Current, processed);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
        {
            EntityCollection<EntityObject> e = (EntityCollection<EntityObject>)p.GetValue(entity, null);
            if (!e.IsLoaded)
                e.Load();

            // Load child entities
            IEnumerator eEnum = e.GetEnumerator();
            while (eEnum.MoveNext())
            {
                LoadAllRelatedEntities((EntityObject)eEnum.Current, processed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also tried:
EntityCollection<IEntityWithRelationships> e = (EntityCollection<IEntityWithRelationships>)p.GetValue(entity, null);

But get the same problem:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[xxx.LLUR.Models.Communication]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithRelationships]'.

Comment: Which version of EF do you use? As far as I remember there was a kind of problem with entities serialization in EF4 with lazy loading enabled which result in serialization of all navigationn properties. Quite useful problem for your case... :)

Comment: Hi Yury, we're using EF 3.5 at the moment so not something I can take advantage of yet :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that did what I want:

```
else if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityCollection<>))
{
    IEnumerable pEnum = (IEnumerable)p.GetValue(entity, null);

    IRelatedEnd pEnd = (IRelatedEnd)p.GetValue(entity, null);
    pEnd.Load();

    // Load child entities
    IEnumerator eEnum = pEnum.GetEnumerator();
    while (eEnum.MoveNext())
    {
        LoadAllRelatedEntities((EntityObject)eEnum.Current, ref processed);
    }
}
```

I also needed to change the `processed` param to a ref so it worked as required:

```
LoadAllRelatedEntities(EntityObject entity, ref List<EntityKey> processed)
```

In my case I also had to add some filtering to which entities I would load as in my case a lot were self-referencing somewhere down the chain and so caused endless looping.